# Allow vertical page breaks when printing wide html pages?

Tags: html, css, printing

Is there a way to allow vertical page breaks when printing a web page containing very wide content (a 4000px x 3000px very detailed svg image in this case).

In ideal scenario it would split the web page into several "tiles".

At the moment it simply zooms out so that entire 4000px width would fit on a single A4 page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the page break property? 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp